# Reorder objects in JS - filter object and map into new one

Tags: javascript

Data

```
const data = [
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "parent": "0",
    "title": "Test-1"
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "parent": "1",
    "title": "Test-1-1"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "parent": "0",
    "title": "Test-2"
  },
  {
    "ID": 4,
    "parent": "0",
    "title": "Test-3"
  },
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "parent": "4",
    "title": "Test-3-1"
  },
  {
    "ID": 6,
    "parent": "4",
    "title": "Test-3-2"
  },
];
```

Operations:

```
let parents = data.filter(item => item.parent == "0");
let parents_children = parents.map(item => item.children = data.filter(stop => stop.parent == item.ID));
```

`console.log(parents_children);` isn't working at all.

`console.log(parents);` is working perfectly. But I don't understand why... How is `let parents_children` affecting `let parents`? Is there a better solution for what I to to archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assignment and return has to be different**

```
let parents_children = parents.map(item => {
   item.children = data.
           filter(stop => stop.parent == item.ID);
   return item;
});
```

**// Better performance**

```
let result = data2.reduce((map, cur) => {
  if (cur.parent === "0") {
    // parent
    map[cur.ID] = map[cur.ID] || { children: [] };
    map[cur.ID] = { ...map[cur.ID], ...cur };
  } else {
    if (!map[cur.parent]) map[cur.parent] = { children: [] };
    map[cur.parent].children.push(cur);
  }
  return map;
}, {});
let finalResult = [];
for (const key in result) {
  finalResult.push(result[key]);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResult, null, 4));
```

Working sample:

```js
const data = [
  { ID: 1, parent: "0", title: "Test-1" },
  { ID: 2, parent: "1", title: "Test-1-1" },
  { ID: 3, parent: "0", title: "Test-2" },
  { ID: 4, parent: "0", title: "Test-3" },
  { ID: 5, parent: "4", title: "Test-3-1" },
  { ID: 6, parent: "4", title: "Test-3-2" }
];

let parents = data.filter(item => item.parent == "0");
let parents_children = parents.map(item => {
  // create new object
  return {
    ...item,
    children : data.filter(stop => stop.parent == item.ID)
  };
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(parents_children, null, 4));
console.log(data);


const data2 = [
  { ID: 1, parent: "0", title: "Test-1" },
  { ID: 2, parent: "1", title: "Test-1-1" },
  { ID: 3, parent: "0", title: "Test-2" },
  { ID: 4, parent: "0", title: "Test-3" },
  { ID: 5, parent: "4", title: "Test-3-1" },
  { ID: 6, parent: "4", title: "Test-3-2" }
];

// Better performance


let result = data2.reduce((map, cur) => {
  if (cur.parent === "0") {
    // parent
    map[cur.ID] = map[cur.ID] || { children: [] };
    map[cur.ID] = { ...map[cur.ID], ...cur };
  } else {
    if (!map[cur.parent]) map[cur.parent] = { children: [] };
    map[cur.parent].children.push(cur);
  }
  return map;
}, {});
let finalResult = [];
for (const key in result) {
  finalResult.push(result[key]);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResult, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```

Comment: @mokorana check, i have updated better option for u.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm!

But one more question to understand everything a bit more: `console.log(data)` doesn't represent the original data anymore. As well as `console.log(parents)` outputs the result as well.

Comment: because, `item.children = data.filter(stop => stop.parent == item.ID);` here u assign `children` wich is assign to otoginal data.

Comment: as recommened, never mutate

Comment: @mokorana Check now! `// create new object` , always create new object like this

Comment: Welcomed your additional comments. Now I understood about mutation and the reduce.function is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return from `.map()` I believe.

Try the following:

```
let parents_children = parents.map(item => {
   item.children = data.filter(stop => stop.parent == item.ID)
   return item;
});
```

I hope this helps!